# getElementById is working in UAT environment but it is not working in PRODUCTION environment

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I am using javascript to show progress bar. When I am accessing UAT link from ie 11 browser it is working fine but when I am accessing PRODUCTION link from same ie 11 browser it is not working.
When I debug code I found that in PRODUCTION environment getElementById returns null.

jsp code

```
<input type="hidden" name="taskMethod"  value="<%=request.getParameter("taskMethod")%>">
```

javascript code

```
if(document.getElementById('taskMethod').value=='openPDFFile')
    showLoading();
```

here

```
document.getElementById('taskMethod')
```

returns null in ie 11 for PROD environment but it is working fine for UAT.

When i investigate, I found that input field doesn't have id attributebut why it is working for UAT.

Note:- Application is deployed on IBM websphere server.

Comment: Well if you are requesting an element by id, the element should have an id...

Comment: Yes, I agreed and when I add id attribute it is working. But my concern is that why same code is working in UAT and not working in PROD???

Comment: Same code working for both UAT and PROD in lower version of IE means ie 8, ie 9.

Comment: being on prod/uat shouldn't make a difference, unless something in the header is causing one to use compatibility mode and one to not (and it assigning an ID for some reason). Either way the code you had shouldn't have worked at all.  Give it an ID and it should work.

Comment: Yes @Mat Taylor, I agreed with you and after adding id it is working fine. But my concern is that why it is working in UAT and not working for PROD in IE 11. And it is working for both UAT and PROD in lower IE versions without adding id attribute.

Comment: Looks like your browser is not running as IE11 on your local version. Open up the developer console and see what it is running in.